# how to find kernel branch and commit corresponding to shipped kernel on nexus device

Tags: android-source

I want to build kernel with some flags enabled for my `Samsung Nexus 10`. Here is the info from android About device.

> **Android version**
>   5.1.1
>   **Kernel Version**
>   3.4.67-g84ad5a4
>   android-build@wpee22.hot.corp.google.com#1
>   Fri Nov 13 21:33:05 UTC 2015
>   **Build Number**
>   LMY49J

I am following this AOSP guide to build the kernel - 
https://source.android.com/source/building-kernels

I have cloned the repo but have no clue which branch and the commit to checkout.

```
arpit@arpit-ubuntu:~/kernel$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/exynos.git
Cloning into 'exynos'...
remote: Sending approximately 874.72 MiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 15, done
remote: Total 3997821 (delta 3353407), reused 3997821 (delta 3353407)
Receiving objects: 100% (3997821/3997821), 874.72 MiB | 9.86 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3353407/3353407), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
arpit@arpit-ubuntu:~/kernel$ cd exynos/
arpit@arpit-ubuntu:~/kernel/exynos$ ls -l
total 0
arpit@arpit-ubuntu:~/kernel/exynos$
```

This directory is empty, so the logic given on AOSP to find commit and branch info from kernel binary logs is not applicable here.

git branch -a returns the following .

```
arpit@arpit-ubuntu:~/kernel/exynos$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-3.4
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-koi-3.10-marshmallow-dr1-wear-release
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-koi-3.10-marshmallow-mr1-wear-release
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-koi-3.18-nougat-mr1-wear-release
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-manta-3.4-adf
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-manta-3.4-jb-mr1
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-manta-3.4-jb-mr1-fr
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-manta-3.4-jb-mr1.1
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-manta-3.4-jb-mr2
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-manta-3.4-kitkat-mr0
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-manta-3.4-kitkat-mr1
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-manta-3.4-kitkat-mr2
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-manta-3.4-lollipop-mr1
  remotes/origin/android-exynos-manta-3.4-lollipop-release
  remotes/origin/master
arpit@arpit-ubuntu:~/kernel/exynos$
```

My possible guess is the branch name is `remotes/origin/android-exynos-manta-3.4-lollipop-mr1`.
But none of the commits in this branch has this substring `84ad5a4` (Obtained from kernel version on device). Google search for string `84ad514` also doesn't return anything.
So I am struck here. I want to use the exact code corresponding to the kernel shipped on my device and not the most recent code on the kernel branch. Can you tell me how to figure out the branch and exact commit corresponding to the shipped kernel on my device.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/exynos.git/+log/android-exynos-manta-3.4-lollipop-mr1
Top commit string is similar to the one you said. 84ad5a4